# Where does the nginx cache folder exist on an AWS AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ami

Where does the nginx cache folder exist on an AWS AMI?  I have recently run into some caching issues with nginx(that I am aware of), but to my surprise I could not find out where this cached file was coming from.

I installed it using yum: sudo yum install nginx.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Some people are saying I dont have any cache, but I dont know how then this is working.  The following configuration will result in giving me the wrong cached files:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
        expires      30d;
}
```

If I turn this off, my site will give me the correct files.  Something clearly is happening.

Comment: Have you looked into the nginx configuration file to see what folder it is configured to store cache data in? If you just installed nginx (as indicated by your question) then it won't be configured to store any cached data anywhere yet.

Comment: I think `expires` directive will send to browser to cache on users computer for 30 days, not on your server so you don't have to search that cache folder.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with my edited post.  So if this is not cache, what is it?

Comment: @Mike5050 It is a directive that adds a header to those resources that tells each browser to cache those files for 30 days, on the user's local computer. That is not a server-side cache layer.

Comment: Okay, must be a browser issue, I tried chrome, debug mode, ctrl +f5, and incognito, and firefox, and the site would still show me old files.

Answer (score 0):

Check for /var/cache/niginx   ref:https://amimoto-ami.com/nginx-cache-controller-more-info/

Comment: I can only see the following there: fontconfig, httpd, ldconfig, man, rpcbind, yum

Answer (score -1):

You need to check this cache directory under

> ls /var/cache/nginx

If you are not able to see any nginx directory it means that you didn't set you basic cache in nginx configuration so you need to check or add this part of the configuration in your files.

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g
             inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
server {
# ...
location / {
    proxy_cache my_cache;
    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
 }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, I understand that I did not enable the cache, but then how could the above configuration be giving me bad files?